# How to count only digits length regex

Tags: regex

Russian phone number has 11 digits, but i couldn't use `a{11}`, because phone number can contain brackets and dashes
My regex: `^([\+]?\d){1,2}([\(\-]*[0-9]{3}[\)\-]*)([0-9\-]{7,9})$`
Number can have from 1 to 2 characters as a country code
then 3 digits with brackets or not as phone operator code
then from 7-9 digits with dashes or not

For example:

```
+7(994)849-45-16
+7(994)849-4516
+7(994)84945-16
+7994849-45-16
```

Question is, how i can count lenght of only digits in regex

Comment: Replace `[0-9\-]{7,9}` with `[0-9](?:-?[0-9]){6,8}`. The country code part must be `\+?\d{1,2}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it counts up to 14 digits

Comment: To restrict the overall number of digits to 11, add `(?!(?:\D*\d){12})` after `^`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?!(?:\D*\d){12})(\+?\d{1,2})([(-]*[0-9]{3}[)-]*)([0-9](?:-?[0-9]){6,8})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KI4bYe/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:\D*\d){12})` - no more than 11 digits are allowed in the string
- `(\+?\d{1,2})` - Group 1: an optional `+` and then 1 or 2 digits
- `([(-]*[0-9]{3}[)-]*)` - Group 2: zero or more `(` or `-` chars, three digits, and then again zero or more `)` or `-` chars
- `([0-9](?:-?[0-9]){6,8})` - Group 3: a digit and then 6 to 8 occurrences of an optional `-` and a digit
- `$` - end of string.